# Carriage Return in HTML using Python

Tags: python, html, carriage-return

This might be very simple, but I have some html code that I've downloaded from a website.  The code looks like this:

```
<P>hello1
world1</P><P>hello2 world2</P><P>hello3
world3</P>
```

I'd like to adjust the html so that it looks like this when you open it in a text file:

```
<P>hello1 world1</P>
<P>hello2 world2</P>
<P>hello3 world3</P>
```

Is there an easy way to include a carriage return (without using \n or BR)?

Comment: Carriage return is `\r`, not `\n`, so including a carriage return without using `\n` is easy. But unless you're using Mac OS 9 or below, you don't want a carriage return without a linefeed. As stated, I think the restriction to not use `\n` doesn't make much sense: what aspect of using `\n` do you not like? Must there be no linefeed characters in the resulting text file, or merely no instances of `\n` in the source code? Is this intended to be a programming puzzle, or is the restriction not to use `\n` a natural requirement that perhaps has become confused?

Comment: Why without \n or BR? Curious

Comment: I'm just trying to maintain the source code to be as similar to the original as possible.  If \n or br will do that, then I guess I can use them.  When I read in this information from a website, is there  a br tag or a \r tag that is not visible?  What is making this code have line breaks when I open the original html code in a text file?

Comment: Here's my source link:  ftp://ftp.sec.gov/edgar/data/1000045/0001193125-11-164700.txt.  It's a company's 10-K.

Comment: The linebreaks you see in a text editor are caused by characters (not tags) in the HTML. On Windows a linebreak is two characters `\r`, followed by `\n`, and likely that's what's in the HTML, although many text editors will understand either `\r\n` or `\n` alone to be a linebreak.

Comment: Okay, thank you.  I'm still new to text and html so this is helpful.

Comment: Simplest thing to start with is probably to read your text into a string `foo`, then do `foo.replace('</P>', '</P>\n')`. That won't do exactly what you ask for your example text, because it won't remove the linebreak in the middle of `hello1 world1`, but it's at least a start and will help make the text a bit more readable.